# Angular FormBuild email validation fails on the init (the value is an object)

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my **Angular v5.1.2** project I'm using `FormBuilder` to create simple form:

```js
this.userDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [{value: this.user.userid || '', disabled: true}, [Validators.required]],
  email: [{value: this.user.email || ''}, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  firstName: [{value: this.user.firstName || ''}, [Validators.required]],
  lastName: [{value: this.user.lastName || ''}, [Validators.required]]
});
```

And I have an issue with `email` field. It becomes invalid after the Form has been initialized. If I switch the initialization of the email field value from object notation to

```js
email: [this.user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
```

the things going work properly.

I made a little investigation and with the help of custom validator I realized that the Form field value is an object and it remains the object until any manual change has been done. For example,

```js
email: [{value: this.user.email || ''}, [Validators.required, this.myCustomValidator]],
```

where

```js
private myCustomValidator(control) {
  console.log(control.value);
}
```

gives following:

- `control.value` is equal to `{ value: 'test@test.test' }` on init
- `control.value` is equal to `'test@test.test'` after edit

That's why I didn't see problems with other fileds: they have only `required` validator and `!!({ value: ... })`  is always `true`.

So, is it possible to use object notation for `FormBuilder` fields initialization and what could be wrong in my case? I'd like to have a possibility to set up options like `{value: 'myValue', disabled: true}` but currently I can't use it due to validators issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular distinguishes so-called **boxed** and **unboxed** values.

Boxed value is a value satisfying the following condition:

```typescript
_isBoxedValue(formState: any): boolean {
  return typeof formState === 'object' && 
        formState !== null &&
        Object.keys(formState).length === 2 && 
        'value' in formState &&
       'disabled' in formState;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7c414fc7463dc90fe189db5ecbf3e5befcde6ff4/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L621-L624

As we can see we should provide both `value` and `disabled` properties for boxed value.

If you pass unboxed value then angular will treat it like a value.

More information could be found here

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/test/form_control_spec.ts#L50-L77